# How do I copy and paste formatting of excel tab to other tabs except a selected sheet using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste the format of a worksheet to my other tabs in excel except for a select few using excel VBA. As my tabs keep changing day to day, I want my code to copy and paste the formats to the sheets on the right of my selected "format" sheet. How do I do so? I was thinking of doing a loop but cant wrap my head around doing that.

```
Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
Dim WshTrg As Worksheet

Set WshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Format")
Set WshTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("02.09.19")

    WshSrc.Cells.Copy
    With WshTrg.Cells
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With


Tried this:

Dim rs As Worksheet
    Sheets("Format").Select
    Selection.Copy
    For Each rs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If rs.Name <> "Base" And rs.Name <> "Format" Then
        ActiveSheet.Paste
   End If
Next rs
```

Comment: Why not just loop over `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` and use an `If` statement to exclude the sheets from which you don't want to copy?

Comment: I tried the bottom code, how could i change it?

Comment: not `And` use `Or`..

Comment: `If rs.Name <> "Base" Or rs.Name <> "Format" Then`

Comment: No don't use an `or` as results will always be true when `rs.Name` is either of the two or neither of the two! I will look at rewriting this for you, stay tuned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
Sub CopyFormat()
  Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
  Dim WshTrg As Worksheet

  On Error Resume Next
  Set WshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Format")
  On Error GoTo 0
  If WshSrc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cannot find Worksheet 'Format'", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
  End If
  WshSrc.Cells.Copy

  For Each WshTrg In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If WshTrg.Name <> "Base" And WshTrg.Name <> "Format" Then
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        WshTrg.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
      End If
  Next WshTrg
  Set WshSrc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @Hanish Kiran - I had to fix code formatting and PasteSpecial, let me know if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, the formatting is good but my numbers and formulas are missing